# Refer to outer function in Javascript (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these lines of javascript code which run when the page is loaded:

```
(function my_function() {
    //my stuff
})();

$("select#myselect").change( function() {
    if ($('select#myselect').val() == '1') {
        timer = setTimeout(my_function, 1000*5); //this line throws the error
    } else {
        if(typeof timer !== 'undefined'){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }
});
```

When the line highlighted is executed it throws:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: my_function is not defined"

How can I fix it?

Comment: As the other two have hinted at, your function is in a closure, which is being called as something akin to an anonomous function, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have what's called a closure going on, whereby you cannot access it (by design). Try this instead (also with some additional improvements...

```
function my_function() {
    //my stuff
}

// Call your function...
my_function();

var $mySelect = $("select#myselect");

$mySelect.on("change", function() {
    if ($mySelect.val() == '1') {
        timer = setTimeout(my_function, 1000*5); //this line throws the error
    } else {
        if(typeof timer !== 'undefined'){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }
});
```

I also cached your look up of `select#myselect` into a variable...because it will improve performance (admittedly marginally). In addition, I used the more preferred and newer `on()` method for your change event.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```js
(function my_function() {
    //my stuff
})();
```

To this:

```js
function my_function() {
    //my stuff
}
my_function();
```

Edit: Your function `my_function` isn't callable in the global scope because this pattern creates a local scope. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) excellent wiki article for more informations.

Comment: @Bergi, I made a comment without thinking about what I was saying.  Removing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to run my_function first, and then run it again with the timer.

```
function my_function() {
    //my stuff
}
my_function();

$("select#myselect").change( function() {
    if ($('select#myselect').val() == '1') {
        timer = setTimeout(my_function, 1000*5); //this line throws the error
    } else {
        if(typeof timer !== 'undefined'){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }
});
```